# Pandas - header doesn't change after dropping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

After dropping a few rows of a DataFrame using Pandas, the header doesn't change; it keeps the way it was before the rows were dropped.

How can I get the updated header?

```
for row in range(rowStart): # rowStart is my index (int). It means it should drop all rows up to this
    df.drop(row, inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

header = list(df) # even assigning the header after the drop, it keeps returning the same as before
print(header)
print('')
print(df) # the DataFrame is ok, without the removed rows (as expected)
```

## Minimal example:

```
data = {
    '': '',
    'asd': '',
    'bfdgfd': '',
    'trytr': '',
    'jlhj': '',
    'Job': 'Revenue',
    'abc123': 1000.00,
    'hey098': 2000.00
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(),
    columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1'])
header = list(df)
print(header)
print('')
print(df)

startRow = 5

for row in range(startRow):
    df.drop(row, inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
header = list(df)
print(header)
print('')
print(df)
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your dataframe. Why are you trying to drop rows this way rather than using indexing to select the rows you want to keep?

Comment: What do you mean by *header*? Column names? If so why would you expect to change them, while dropping rows?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski by "header" I mean the values of the rows with index 0 of all columns. I tried using "iloc" too. Same issue.

Comment: @Craig, the data can't be pasted here It's sensitive. Anyway, as I said to Grzegorz, using "list(df)" or similar methods after using "iloc" or "df.drop()" end up the same way.

Comment: You could make up data that has a similar structure and could be used to reproduce your problem. Without the data, this isn't an [mcve].

Comment: But by doing this: `header = list(df)` you essentially assign column names (or at least that's what it does in my version of `pandas`, so it is supposed to remain untouched

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski, shouldn't "drop" and "reset_index" create a new object, so the header would be based on it (in my case, without the first rows)?

Comment: Btw instead of your `for` loop just use: `df.drop(list(df.index)[:rowStart], inplace=True)`

Comment: But headers are column names - it should remain exactly the same after both drop (concerns rows in your case) and reset_index (concerns index)

Comment: The column headers are not the first row of your dataframe. They are determined when you create your dataframe. If you show us sample data, it should be easy for someone to help you.

Comment: @Craig, you and GrzegorzSkibinski are right. Droppng rows or selecting the range doesn't change the column names. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, the "header" is the name of the columns and is stored separately from the data in the dataframe. Based on your comments, I think you need to change the column names first and then drop the rows.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    '': '',
    'asd': '',
    'bfdgfd': '',
    'trytr': '',
    'jlhj': '',
    'Job': 'Revenue',
    'abc123': 1000.00,
    'hey098': 2000.00
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data.items(),
    columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1'])
startRow = 5

df.columns = df.loc[startRow].to_list()  # set the "header" to the values in this row
df = df.loc[startRow+1:].reset_index(drop=True)  # select only the rows you want
```

After this code, df will be:

```
      Job Revenue
0  abc123    1000
1  hey098    2000
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked. The only change I had to do was to set the index for "df.columns" to 0, since I am dropping rows and reseting the indexes. Thank you!

Comment: I made a few adjustments to the code so you won't have to change the index for df.columns.

Comment: Amazing. I noticed that it's also important to set the columns before dropping rows. Otherwise one will end up with either the first row (0) duplicated or missing / no header.